# Why my custom activity never returns?

Tags: service, workflow, bookmarks

I'm a newbie to WF and rather lost.  Here's what I have so far:

I've created a workflow service app (xamlx), added needed variables
I've created a custom NativeActivity where I'm calling CreateBookmark from within Execute, which is between the Receive & Send activity for the service. (Ultimately this will actually do something besides creating the bookmark).

The bookmark gets created just fine, but after stepping out of the Execute method, nothing happens for one minute until the service times out, giving me that message "The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9699970. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout." (I tried posting an image of the xamlx, but as a newbie it won't let me; suffice it to say I'm getting from my Receive, into my custom native activity, but never getting as far as the SendReply).

I assume I'm missing something rather fundatmental, but I can't see what.  I've originally tried using NativeActivity<T> to return what I want, but that behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what I was doing wrong:  needed to use overload of CreateBookmark that has BookmarkOptions parameter and set it to BookmarkOptions.NonBlocking.

Strangely, I did not find one example anywhere that mentioned this.